# Mr Ling Designed My Jewellery

Tags: wordplay, knowledge, movies

I wonder about my wife sometimes. She's getting harder to comprehend all the time.

Take last weekend, for example:
my nephew had come over to visit and was telling me all about the movie club that he's been enjoying this year at school. I had to admit that I hadn't heard of most of the films, but they sounded interesting.
That evening, when I was telling my wife about it, she looked strangely at me then burst out laughing.
I asked her what was so funny and she said "Your earring is a Paul Ling".

The thing is, I don't wear any earrings.

Anyway, here is the list of films my nephew told me about:

> Sergei Ivanov enjoys his favourite meal of stroganoff in the canteen at work. (7,4)
>   After Mr. Rhames had finished using his towel, he longed for the climate control of his former apartment. (3,4,6,1.1.)
>   At the annual conference of the UK's media and entertainment trade union, there is a special session on the lack of seating. (5:3,3,6)
>   Bruce Froemming has never really listened to classical music so he settles down to the Brandenburg Concertos. (3,6,5,4)
>   A documentary about aggregates which are used to clean up donkey vomit. (3,4,2,4,4)
>   Remy and Splinter are recruited by the CIA, but they spend their first mission feasting on the fruit of the Ceratonia siliqua. (3,4,5,3,5,4)
>   Another documentary, this time about the slate-coloured cloak that batman uses when he's experimenting. (3,4,4,4)
>   Mr. Disney takes all his staff out for a meal. (4'1,5)
>   A father gives his boy explicit instructions that the grizzly dosed with novocain is not to be moved. (3,4,4,5,3)
>   Everyone keeps repeating this shout of encouragement to Aragorn. (2,7!)
>   The head of the company was furious with the payroll team when an underperforming member of staff was sacked and they didn't deduct enough money from her final pay packet. (6,3,3,6)
>   When I was in Dublin, I fell in the river and now I smell horrible. (2,6,5)
>   You can hear Homer Simpson's voice explaining how to make carpet from yarns. (3,4,"5,5")
>   A man goes to the doctor with an unusal complaint - he thinks he's a low platform for a lecturn or throne. (1'1,1,4)
>   The midfielder passes the ball to Nick Burkhardt and the defenders appeal for a free kick, but there are still two players between him and the goal line. (5'1,6)
>   After Washington Spirit's latest victory, Tori and her family get caught in the rain. (3,4,7)
>   Hannibal Lecter had no regrets about consuming his auntie. (4,2,3,3)

**Question:** Have you any idea why my wife said that to me?

Comment: I'm really not into cryptic clue puzzles, but reading examples like your question (plus the answers) gets me more and more interested. +1

Comment: @Gordon K: any chance that the "The head of the company..." Clue involves spelling or terms that a Yank like me wouldn't normally use?

Comment: @axavio I'm quite sure all the words are well known both sides of the Atlantic. Don't concentrate on the head of the company. Focus on what the payroll team did.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your wife said:

> Your hearing is appalling!

Full Answer (Yay Team!)

Remember -- ***teamwork makes the dream work!***:

Sergei Ivanov enjoys his favourite meal of stroganoff in the canteen at work. (7,4)

> Kremlin stew -> Gremlins 2 (thanks [@Daphne B](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/12092/daphne-b))

After Mr. Rhames had finished using his towel, he longed for the climate control of his former apartment. (3,4,6,1.1.)

> Dry Ving misswd A.C. -> Driving Miss Daisy

At the annual conference of the UK's media and entertainment trade union, there is a special session on the lack of seating. (5:3,3,6)

> BECTU:the few chairs -> Back to the Future

Bruce Froemming has never really listened to classical music so he settles down to the Brandenburg Concertos. (3,6,5,4)

> The umpire tries Bach -> The Empire Strikes Back

A documentary about aggregates which are used to clean up donkey vomit. (3,4,2,4,4)

> The sand of mule sick -> The Sound of Music (thanks [@Ken Y-N](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/341/ken-y-n))

Remy and Splinter are recruited by the CIA, but they spend their first mission feasting on the fruit of the Ceratonia siliqua. (3,4,5,3,5,4)

> Spy rats scoff the carob bean -> Pirates of the Caribbean (thanks [@Gareth McCaughan](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/19114/gareth-mccaughan))

Another documentary, this time about the slate-coloured cloak that batman uses when he's experimenting. (3,4,4,4)

> The Gray Test Cape -> The Great Escape

Mr. Disney takes all his staff out for a meal. (4'1,5)

> Walt's treat -> Wall Street

A father gives his boy explicit instructions that the grizzly dosed with novocain is not to be moved. (3,4,4,5,3)

> The Numb Bear stays, son  -> The Numbers Station (thank [@Mizu](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/20676/mizu))

Everyone keeps repeating this shout of encouragement to Aragorn. (2,7!)

> Go Strider -> Ghost Rider

The head of the company was furious with the payroll team when an underperforming member of staff was sacked and they didn't deduct enough money from her final pay packet. (6,3,3,6)

> docked her too little -> Doctor Doolittle  (thanks [@Mike M.](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/2717/mike-m))

When I was in Dublin, I fell in the river and now I smell horrible. (2,6,5)

> My Liffey scent-> Maleficent (thanks [@Daphne B](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/12092/daphne-b))

You can hear Homer Simpson's voice explaining how to make carpet from yarns. (3,4,"5,5")

> Dan says "weave wools" -> Dances with Wolves  (thanks [@Mike M.](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/2717/mike-m))

A man goes to the doctor with an unusual complaint - he thinks he's a low platform for a lectern or throne. (1'1,1,4)

> I'm a dais -> Amadeus

The midfielder passes the ball to Nick Burkhardt and the defenders appeal for a free kick, but there are still two players 
between him and the goal line. (5'1,6)

> Grimm's Onside -> Crimson Tide

After Washington Spirit's latest victory, Tori and her family get caught in the rain. (3,4,7)

> The damp Husters -> The Dam Busters

Hannibal Lecter had no regrets about consuming his auntie. (4,2,3,3)

> glad he ate her -> Gladiator (thanks Daphne and Gareth!)

Comment: So the wife is fine and it is hpthe husband with bad comprehension?

Comment: @John Miao: As far as I can tell, it's only the husband with the problem.

Comment: @axavio In your answer to "Remy and Splinter are recruited by the CIA, (...)" - could the missing word (????) be "off"?

Comment: @axavio And what the missing 5-word on "A father gives his boy..." is "stays"?

Comment: @Mizu:  thanks. I betcha it's "quaff" since it needs to be 5 letters. I will try "stays"

Comment: Homer is voiced by Dan Castellaneta, and I believe he "says weave wools". Make sense?

Comment: In Dublin, the "scent" of Liffey belongs to me...

Comment: @DaphneB is it about the movie of that lady with some nice horns? :D

Comment: @Mizu: yes.  And another thing, Sergei Ivanov isn't just any old Russian.  He used to work in a certain building.

Comment: I just figured out Hannibal's deal as well.  If you ask him, "How did you feel about consuming that lady?" he might say, "I was..."...

Comment: @axavio "After Washington Spirit's latest..." - 3-word could be "wet", right? (because of the rain)

Comment: @DaphneB is on a roll!  I am trying to catch up.

Comment: ♫The Hills Are Alive With The Sand of Mule Sick♫

Comment: Good progress so far. A couple of notes: There's a word that rhymes with "quaff" that means to eat, rather than to drink. In your second-last one, check the spelling of the name you've filled in (NB I've also just changed the letter count of the last word in this clue as it works better with the plural version).

Comment: @DaphneB : still clueless on Hannibal. I was fond of mom sis?  Full of ??

Comment: ("Scoff", as Gordon suggests. The fact that it starts with an "s" also helps it sound right.)

Comment: Daphne: I think the version needed for the clue here is the answer to "How did *he* feel about consuming that lady". Otherwise the second word is the wrong length and doesn't sound quite right.

Comment: axavio, note that Hannibal had no regrets. So not "fond of mom sis" or anything like that.

Comment: @axavio For the Hannibal clue, he probably feels this way about most girls he's cannibalized, not just his aunt.

Comment: @Aethon : I had just got it!  Finally.  Whew. Prolly the last one here.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan: yup, I was going with an infinitive there and I didn't see that there was a better way.  You were right.

Comment: Got it! Not sure how to help, here. Don't wanna be as blatant as last time. :-) The CEO would say this while yelling at the staff. "You deducted an insufficient amount from her pay!"

Comment: Nicely done! Hope you enjoyed it.

Comment: @Gordon K:   That was truly a fun one.  Thanks for the top-notch puzzle!