# Stop Shoeing Our Shrubs

Tags: wordplay, knowledge, music

Vandalism these days comes in many strange and varied forms.

I told you about my [nephew's film club](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/35591/mr-ling-designed-my-jewellery). This weekend it was the turn of my niece to visit.

She was suggesting that there are people at her university who go around fitting footwear to plants.
This sort of behaviour is clearly damaging certain species, so she has been lending her support to a **Quinine Tree Boot Ban**. 
They obviously provide entertainment while they are protecting the flora, as she told me about some of the songs they were singing:

> Some sort of adhesive plant resin. (2'1,1,4,2,6)
>   Unconventional rubus fruit. (8,9)
>   The poor man had been in a terrible accident and had spokes sticking out of his cheeks and forehead. (7,4)
>   I'm moving out. Every day here I find faeces and I won't tolerate it. (1,3'1,4,4,3)
>   I resent being charged for making cakes and pies. (1,4,2,4,4)
>   You'll find it if you consult the cartographers on Mount Olympus. (2,3,3,2,3,4)
>   Someone choked on a borlotti. (6,4)
>   St Peter's eggs are… (4,2,6)
>   Inhaling a surfeit of tobacco is inevitably fatal. (3,4,5,4,4,3)
>   Footwear from a seaside resort. (8,4)
>   Take care when you are feeding the ducks that you never drop the bag. (3'1,4,4,5)
>   Praying for Her Majesty to wake up bald. (3,5,3,5)

When I told my wife about it later, she just looked at me and shook her head.

**Question:** What had I done wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some that APrough hasn't got yet [EDITED to add:] ... in fact, I think that's all of them now.

Unconventional rubus fruit. (8,9)

> Bohemian raspberry [rhapsody] (Queen) -- it seems clear that Jeodesic already got this one.

I'm moving out. Every day here I find faeces and I won't tolerate it. (1,3'1,4,4,3)

> I can't live with poo [you] (Queen)

I resent being charged for making cakes and pies. (1,4,2,4,4)

> I want to bake [break] free (Queen)

You'll find it if you consult the cartographers on Mount Olympus. (2,3,3,2,3,4)

> In the map [lap] of the gods (Queen)

Someone choked on a borlotti. (6,4)

> Killer bean [queen] (Queen)

St Peter's eggs are ... (4,2,6)

> Laid [made] in heaven (Queen)

Inhaling a surfeit of tobacco is inevitably fatal. (3,4,5,4,4,3)

> Too much snuff [love] will kill you (Queen)

Footwear from a seaside resort. (8,4)

> Brighton Sock [rock] (Queen)

Take care when you are feeding the ducks that you never drop the bag. (3'1,4,4,5)

> Don't lose your bread [head] (Queen)

It seems clear that there's a definite

> Queen-y theme -- in fact a more specific one than I thought, because it turns out Queen did actually record something called "God save the Queen". I don't know whether it's just a version of the national anthem or a different thing of their own.

so "Quinine Tree Boot Ban"

> is a mishearing of something beginning with "Queen", though I haven't worked out what yet. [EDITED to add: Jeodesic suggests in comments to APrough's answer that it might be "Queen tribute band", as does Business Cat in comments here -- which is pretty plausible though it seems to be missing a syllable.]

Comment: Could it simply be Queen Tribute Band?

Comment: dangit, I just posted my answer and refreshed the page to see you'd already got them all.

Comment: whrrgarbl, sorry!

Comment: nah, I was still missing the footwear and tobacco clues - +1 for you :)

Comment: I'm glad someone had the energy and mental capacity to figure it out.  I hit a wall - +1

Comment: I still think Jeodesic should have the +15. Oh well.

Answer (score 1):

Working list

Some sort of adhesive plant resin. (2'1,1,4,2,6)

Unconventional rubus fruit. (8,9)

The poor man had been in a terrible accident and had spokes sticking out of his cheeks and forehead. (7,4)

> Bicycle Face (Bicycle Race by Queen)

I'm moving out. Every day here I find faeces and I won't tolerate it. (1,3'1,4,4,3)

I resent being charged for making cakes and pies. (1,4,2,4,4)

You'll find it if you consult the cartographers on Mount Olympus. (2,3,3,2,3,4)

Someone choked on a borlotti. (6,4)

St Peter's eggs are… (4,2,6)

Inhaling a surfeit of tobacco is inevitably fatal. (3,4,5,4,4,3)

Footwear from a seaside resort. (8,4)

Take care when you are feeding the ducks that you never drop the bag. (3'1,4,4,5)

Praying for Her Majesty to wake up bald. (3,5,3,5)

> God Shave the Queen (God Save the Queen - British national anthem)

Comment: The raspberry is an example of a rubus fruit. :) And I believe these songs are all by the same band - "Quinine Tree Boot Ban" = Queen tribute band.

Comment: Jeodesic, it seems clear that you actually figured out what was going on before anyone else did. Perhaps you should submit an answer...